# Flatten javascript array with Multi-dimensional data

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

How can one flatten this in javascript?

```
[
    [ task: 2 ],
    [ status: 'REFUND' ],
    [],
    [ amount: 872.2 ] 
]
```

To something like:

```
[task: 2, status: 'REFUND', amount: 872.2]
```

Tried several options including Array.prototype.reduce() but did not work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: You mean { task : 2 } etc. right ?

Comment: No tomdemuyt. I get above from an array.push(), like this:
var a = [];
var b = [];
var c = [];
a[task] = 2;
b[status] = 'REFUND';

c.push(a)
c.push(b)

For some reason I cannot put them in one variable. They come from different functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join()`

A good starting point:

```
array[0] = array[0].join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use underscore.js

```
var u = require('underscore');
u.reduce(a, function(memo, item) { 
    var o = {}; 
    u.each(memo, function(v, k) { 
        o[k] = v; 
    }); 
    u.each(item, function(v, k) { 
        o[k] = v; 
    }); 
    return o;
});
```

---

Input:

```
[
    { task: 2 },
    { status: 'REFUND' },
    {},
    { amount: 872.2 }
]
```

Output:

```
{ 
   task: 2,
   status: 'REFUND',
   amount: 872.2 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't underscore have a flatten method?

Comment: Underscore does have a flatten method. But you cannot use it in this case. It would have worked if it was an array of an array. But since its an array of an object _.flatten would return the input itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid; there is no `:` allowed outside of an object literal.

```
var arr = [
  [{task: 2}],[{status: 'REFUND'}],[],[{amount: 872.2}]
];
```

To flatten your array, use the versatile `reduce`:

```
var result = arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
  return a.concat(b)
}); //result.length === 3
```

Your result contains 3 elements as `[]` is filter out

`reduce` is part of *ECMAScript 5th edition*. Ensure your browser supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one.

```
var a = [], b = [],c = [],d=[]; 
 a['task'] = 2;
 b['status'] = 'REFUND';
 d['amount']= 872.2

 c.push(a); 
 c.push(b);
 c.push(d) 
 var arr = [];
console.log(c)

for(var key in c){
    //console.log(Object.keys(c[key]),c[key][Object.keys(c[key])]);
     arr[Object.keys(c[key])]=c[key][Object.keys(c[key])];
   }

 console.log(arr)  // please see the console.
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/J6wdA7zScOHddLbTXvGP?p=preview)